# on my local network my app works but on the internet it doesn't, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

hello i'm almost done with this project my question is why wont it work on Heroku it will run on my local network though what it does on my machine I'll login and it pops up with a table with all the users data (readings), but when I run it though Heroku and login with the right credentials it gives me an error of User Name or password Incorrect?, why? here is my back end for login ...

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const connection = require('../../db/Connection');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const JWT_SECRET = 'wesleysecret';

const SELECT_USER_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM users';

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
let { userName, password = req.body.password } = req.query;

connection.query(
SELECT_USER_QUERY + ` WHERE userName=?`,
[userName],
(error, results) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  if (!userName || !password) {
    return res.status(400).send({ message: 'No info' });
  } else {
    if (results.length > 0 || password === '') {
      bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, (err, result) => {
        if (result) {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              userName: results[0].userName,
              password: results[0].password
            },
            JWT_SECRET,
            {
              expiresIn: '30s',
            }
          );
          res.header('auth-token', token);
          return res.send({ message: 'Login Successful' });
        } else {
          return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Invalid Password' });
        }
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Invalid userName' });
    }
  }
}
);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my front end...

```
handleLogIn = async () => {
const { userName, password, isLogedIn } = this.state.user;
const { users } = this.state;

await postFetch(`/users/login`, {
  userName,
  password,
})
  .then((result) => {
    //handle wrong password
    if (!result.message) {
      console.log(result.errors);
      return;
    } else if (result.message === 'Invalid userName') {
      this.setState({
        user: {
          ...this.state.user,
          loginError: 'Registration Required',
        },
      });
    } else if (result.message === 'Invalid Password') {
      this.setState({
        user: {
          ...this.state.user,
          loginError: 'User Name or password incorrect',
        },
      });
    } else if (result.message === 'No info') {
      this.setState({
        user: {
          ...this.state.user,
          loginError: 'Enter userName and password',
        },
      });
    } else if (result.message === 'Login Successful') {
      let user = users.find((user) => user.userName === userName);
      this.setState({
        user: {
          ...this.state.user,
          id: user.id,
          firstName: user.firstName,
          lastName: user.lastName,
          userName: user.userName,
          password: user.password,
          email: user.email,
          isLogedIn: !isLogedIn,
          loginError: '',
        },
      });
      this.getPreference(user.id);
      this.getReadings(user.id);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Also don't know if I need to tell you this but back end is in java script and front end is in reactjs

here is my database connection...

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit: 10,
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
user: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASS,
port: process.env.DB_PORT,
database: process.env.DB,
multipleStatements: true,
});

connection.getConnection((err, connection) => {
if (err) {
if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
  console.error('Database connection was closed.');
}
if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
  console.error('Database has too many connections.');
}
if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
  console.error('Database connection was refused.');
}
} else {
console.log('MySql connected successfully');
}
if (connection) connection.release();
return;
});

module.exports = connection;
```

Comment: where is your database located in?

Comment: ^^^ can you share the database configuration

Comment: a file called db/Connection.js... and I think I forgot to say that I can add a user but can't login

Comment: do I need to use Sequelize  instead of plain MySQL